# Different function if key pressed again

Tags: autohotkey

So far my code looks like this:

```
capslock::
send FIRST FUNCTION
send {capslock up}
keywait, capslock,d
send SECOND FUNCTION
return
```

Doesn't work, always performs first function, then second.
What I'm trying to do is esentially a toggle.
Pressed - first function, Pressed- second function, Pressed- first function and so on.
Any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to create a toggle, is to check the value of some variable and then change its value, like this:

```
CapsLock::
    if (toggle) ;if true
    {
        ToolTip, action2
        toggle := false
    }
    else ;else (if false)
    {
        ToolTip, action1
        toggle := true
    }
return
```